# How to trigger an AWS sagemaker pipeline with an irregular cadenced schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sagemaker, aws-event-bridge

I know that SageMaker pipelines are tightly integrated with EventBridge to schedule their execution. However, EventBridge's functionalities do not provide me with the flexibility that I need.

EventBridge allows you to set up triggers based on the occurrence of a particular event or on a recurring schedule.

I need my pipeline to execute on a schedule but unfortunately it is not as simple as once a week or once month. My schedule is based on a business calendar where the cadence is sometimes 4 weeks and sometimes 5 weeks. EventBridge does not allow for this flexibility.

So my question is what is my best option to allow for this type of flexible schedule?

I have two ideas in my head:

1. One idea was to create a step at the beginning of my pipeline that would calculate if it was the right week to run or not and then use a condition step that would take the output to either continue or halt the pipeline.
2. Run a lambda function on weekly schedule that determines whether it is the right week to run or not. If it is, it can trigger the sagemaker pipeline.

Are these valid options? Is one more appropriate than the other? Are there other ideas that would be more appropriate?

Thank you.

Comment: Both of your options are basically the same thing - put some code in front to determine if you should really run.  I would lean towards option 2 but, honestly, that's a personal preference not a solid technical benefit.

Comment: Yeah I would prefer using Lambda to do the checks and then trigger pipeline. At least it keeps the pipeline flow clean and simple.

Comment: Yeah I realize they accomplish the same thing but I'm trying to understand what the "AWS way" is since I'm pretty new to AWS in general. I.e. what tool(s) are most appropriate for what I'm trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

Referring to this [page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/schedule-types.html#rate-based), there seems to be a scheduler where you can just type

```
rate(35 days)
```

#### EDIT

Editing based on your comment. If you need it at alternate interval between 28 and 35 days, another option is to pre-calculate the schedules for the foreseeable future. You can use EventBridge's `One-time schedules` from the same link above and pre-create the schedules using `aws scheduler create-schedule`.

Example,

```
at(2023-01-01T01:23:45)
at(2023-02-05T01:23:45)
at(2023-03-05T01:23:45)
at(2023-04-09T01:23:45)
at(2023-05-07T01:23:45)
...
```

In my opinion, changing your architecture and adding another component for ops to maintain (which may involve vulnerability scan, runtime update, additional efforts of troubleshooting, etc.) seems an overkill for a scheduling requirement, which is why I have been offering alternatives.

Comment: I need it to alternate between 28 and 35 days

Comment: Okay. I thought you just need some workloads to run every 28 days, some every 35 days. Updated answer.

Comment: This solution makes sense and is worth considering. In the end, we went with the conditional step within the sagemaker pipeline. It does add an extra "step" in the pipeline but at least everything is still in the sagemaker eco-system.